# PHP include while mysql query

Tags: php, mysql

Code

```
$groups = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM Exten WHERE username='" . $user . "'") or die(mysqli_error($con));
while ($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($groups)) {
    $userindex = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM Exten WHERE Group1='" . $rows['Group1'] . "''" . include "var/www/html/groups.php" . "'") or die(mysqli_error($con));
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($userindex)) {
    echo "<br>";
    echo $row['Index'];
    }
}
```

The output message is

> Warning: include(var/www/html/groups.php'): failed to open stream: No
>   such file or directory in /var/www/html/login.php on line 38
>
> Warning: include(): Failed opening 'var/www/html/groups.php'' for
>   inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /var/www/html/login.php
>   on line 38 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near ''01''' at line 1

I need to include my php file to my mysql query.

PHP file consists of

```
OR Group2='" . $rows['Group2'] . "'
OR Group3='" . $rows['Group3'] . "'
OR Group4='" . $rows['Group4'] . "'
OR Group5='" . $rows['Group5'] . "'
OR Group6='" . $rows['Group6'] . "'
OR Group7='" . $rows['Group7'] . "'
OR Group8='" . $rows['Group8'] . "'
OR Group9='" . $rows['Group9'] . "'
OR Group10='" . $rows['Group10'] . "'
```

Comment: $userindex = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM Exten WHERE Group1='" . $rows['Group1'] . "''" . include "groups.php" . "'") or die(mysqli_error($con));

Comment: I don't think include can behave as a function that would return data. If it's just text content you're trying to include, I suggest having a text file and loading it with `file_get _contents` instead

Comment: @apokryfos yes, [it can](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php). _"It is possible to execute a return statement inside an included file in order to terminate processing in that file and return to the script which called it. Also, it's possible to return values from included files. You can take the value of the include call as you would for a normal function"_

Comment: Edited my question so you can see what i want to include

Comment: Well then, I stand corrected, although what @RuslanBes linked to does give a good reason as to why this code does not work.

Answer (score 0):

The file path is incorrect, it needs to start with a forward slash `/` to read: 
`/var/www/html/groups.php`

Also, why are you using an include statement within the MySQL query?

Comment: Because i need to include about a 100 strings of OR statement

Comment: The file path was indeed originally incorrect. If you still get error `failed to open stream`, then you need to make sure you have proper permissions to read that file. Can you ensure the permissions? If you are executing this script via the browser, then you need to make sure that this file is either owned by the same user that executes php scripts, or that it shares the same group.

Comment: Edited my question so you can see what i want to include

Comment: @Zajev did you read my comment? Are you still getting the same `failed to open stream` error after fixing the file path to be: `/var/www/html/groups.php`?
If so, it is a file permissions issue. Do you know how file permissions work?

Answer (score 0):

The file path seems to have an extra single quote at the end:

```
Warning: include(var/www/html/groups.php')
```

What happens if you use:

```
include ("var/www/html/groups.php")
```

or

```
include ("/var/www/html/groups.php")
```

with brackets rather than just quotes? Also, check your quotes otherwise your query might break.

Answer (score -1):

If `var` is at the root, then write it like `include "./var/www/html/groups.php"`

```
$userindex = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM Exten WHERE Group1='" . $rows['Group1'] . "''" . include "./var/www/html/groups.php" . "'") or die(mysqli_error($con));
```